# How to create a new PhoneGap Android project in Eclipse "Juno" on Mac?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I recently reinstalled my OS, and used to have a PhoneGap / Android project.  Now I want to use it again, so I reinstalled Eclipse and the ADT plug in.  So far so good.  Now the instructions say:

"Choose New > Android Project"

However, Android Project doesn't show up under new projects, like it used to.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

I downloaded phonegap-2.6.0, but perhaps it isn't connected to Eclipse... what do I do at this stage to get Android Project to show up?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no 'Android Project' under the menu it is not about PhoneGap it is maybe about ADT, are you sure you installed it correctly ?
And, also you can create Android Project with PhoneGap by using 'command line', then you just go to the same menu:" New > Project " then choose Android Project with existing source choose the path you created before by command line and that's it.

**edit1: Make sure you locate true directory for 'android-sdk-mac_x86'**

**edit2:this is how you create Android project by using Terminal**

```
/path/to/cordova-android/bin/create /path/to/my_new_cordova_project com.example.cordova_project_name CordovaProjectName
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me, Eclipse wouldn't respond when I clicked **Finish** when importing source from a **phonegap** project.

I later found that I had mentioned an incorrect path to the android-sdk.

Check if that is your problem.

If it is, here is how you change it:

1. In Eclipse IDE, click on the **Window** menu and then **Preferences**.
2. A pop-up will be opened.
3. On the left pane, click on **Android** (click *on* it, not on the **+** sign beside it).
4. In the field **SDK Location**, click **Browse** and point to the location of your android-sdk.
5. You are done!

Hope that helped.

**EDIT:**

I am using Eclipse Juno, but the options must hopefully be pretty much the same for other versions too. Please comment if this is incorrect.